# Converting a hexadecimal Integer into a character using explicit type conversion?

Tags: java, type-conversion, hex

I coded the following, But the o/p is not the expected ? Someone Guide me?

Question: Write a sample program to declare a hexadecimal integer and covert it into a character using explicit type Conversion?

```
class hexa
{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
    int hex=0xA;
    System.out.println(((char)hex));
}
}
```

please tell me :
        Why there is a difference in output

```
/*code 1*/
int hex = (char)0xA; 
System.out.println(hex); 
/*code 2*/
int hex = 0xA; 
System.out.println((char)hex);
```

Comment: What was the output and what was your expectation?

Comment: Why there is a difference in output??? 
/*code 1*/
int hex = (char)0xA; 
System.out.println(hex); 
/*code 2*/
int hex = 0xA; 
System.out.println((char)hex);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int hex = 0xA; 
System.out.println( (char)hex );
```

The hex value 0xA (or decimal 10) is "\n" (new line feed char) in ASCII.

Hence the output.

EDIT (thanks to [halex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637284/halex) for providing the correction in comments:

```
int hex = (char) 0xA;
System.out.println(hex); //here value of hex is '10', type of hex is 'int', the overloaded println(int x) is invoked.

int hex = 0xA;
System.out.println((char) hex); //this is equivalent to System.out.println( '\n' ); since the int is cast to a char, which produces '\n', the overloaded println(char x) is invoked.
```

Comment: Why there is a difference in output 
/*code 1*/
int hex = (char)0xA; 
System.out.println(hex); 
/*code 2*/
int hex = 0xA; 
System.out.println((char)hex);

Comment: Concerning your edit: In the comments to the code you write that `toString` is called on `int` and `char` but that is not correct. There is no autoboxing but the appropriate overloaded version of `println` is called for [`int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) and [`char`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char)) types.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the letter `A` to be printed.
Instead of `print` use [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

```
int hex=0xA;
System.out.printf("%X%n", hex);
```

Comment: If that is the case, well what is the %n does

Comment: Newline. Without that printf is more like `print` rather than `println`.